# Keep React pop up from going away after new onClicks are registered

Tags: reactjs, next.js, popup, timeout, react-state

I'm creating a custom popup in React that shows up after a button click, and I want to go away from the screen after X amount of seconds. The issue I'm running into is that if you click the button multiple times before the initial timeout ends, you get very strange behavior like the popup jumping in and out or just not showing up at all.

I realize that this is due to me misusing React state, but how can I get around this issue?

```
function popupHandler(popupText, setPopupVis, setPopupText) {
    setPopupText(popupText)
    setPopupVis("visible");
    // Works when you click a button ONCE and then don't touch anything during the timeout windows
    // Totally breaks if you do otherwise. 
    // I want to "extend" the timeout so that the 
    //  popup window keeps staying up if the button keeps getting clicked
    setTimeout(() => {
        setPopupVis("hidden")
    }, 3000);
}

function CustomButton({setPopupText, setPopupVis}) {
    return (
        <button onClick={() => popupHandler("Dynamic string", setPopupText, setPopupVis)}>
            I am a button
        </button>
    )
}

function MyPopUp({popupVis, popupText}) {
    return (
        <div style={{visibility: popupVis}}>
            {popupText}
        </div>
    )
}

export default function MyContent() {
    const [popupVis, setPopupVis] = useState('hidden');
    const [popupText, setPopupText] = useState('')
    return (
        <>
            <CustomButton setPopupText={setPopupText} setPopupVis={setPopupVis} />
            <MyPopUp popupVis={popupVis} popupText={popupText} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required functionality by adding another state variable that keeps track of your setTimeout() timers.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function popupHandler(popupText, setPopupVis, setPopupText, popupTimer, setPopupTimer) {
  setPopupText(popupText);
  setPopupVis("visible");
  // YOU NEED THIS
  if (popupTimer) {
    clearTimeout(popupTimer);
  }
  setPopupVis("visible");
  const newTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      setPopupVis("hidden");
  }, 5000);
  setPopupTimer(newTimer);
}

function CustomButton({ setPopupText, setPopupVis, popupTimer, setPopupTimer}) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => popupHandler("Dynamic string", setPopupText, setPopupVis, popupTimer, setPopupTimer)}
    >
      I am a button
    </button>
  );
}

function MyPopUp({ popupVis, popupText }) {
  return <div style={{ visibility: popupVis }}>{popupText}</div>;
}

export default function MyContent() {
  const [popupVis, setPopupVis] = useState("hidden");
  const [popupText, setPopupText] = useState("");
  // YOU NEED THIS
  const [popupTimer, setPopupTimer] = useState(null);

  return (
    <>
      <CustomButton setPopupText={setPopupText} setPopupVis={setPopupVis} popupTimer={popupTimer} setPopupTimer={setPopupTimer} />
      <MyPopUp popupVis={popupVis} popupText={popupText} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `popupHandler` access to `popusVis`. If `popupVis` is already "visible", return early:

```
function popupHandler(popupVis, popupText setPopupVis, setPopupText) {

    // Return early if it's already visible
    if (popupVis === "visible")
        return

    // Your code
}
```